# Listing lines from just one file in DIFF

Tags: linux, diff

I would like to get (GNU)DIFF to printout only lines that are different in one file.
So given

```
    ==> diffa.txt <==
    line1
    line2 - in a only
    line3
    line4 changed
    line5

    ==> diffb.txt <==
    line1
    line3
    line4 changed in b
    line5
    line6 in b only
```

i would like `diff --someoption diffa.txt diffb.txt` to produce

```
    line2 - in a only

    line4 changed
```

The following looks as though it should be helpful but it is a bit cryptic :

```
   --GTYPE-group-format=GFMT
          Similar, but format GTYPE input groups with GFMT.

   --line-format=LFMT
          Similar, but format all input lines with LFMT.

   --LTYPE-line-format=LFMT
          Similar, but format LTYPE input lines with LFMT.

   LTYPE is `old', `new', or `unchanged'.
          GTYPE is LTYPE or `changed'.

          GFMT may contain:

   %<     lines from FILE1

   %>     lines from FILE2
```

Comment: The man page is definitely a bit terse on these flags! Good question.

Comment: I would like to point out that ' info diff ' will give complete examples, there is a wealth of information in info.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Not sure `diff` alone can do it but you can always use the power of other GNU utilities to help you.

```
diff -u diffa.txt diffb.txt | grep '^-[^-]' | sed 's/^-//'
```

It does the diff, then selects only the lines that begins with '-' - those are changed and have values from diffa.txt file, then `sed` just remove those '-' signs.

**Edit:** After few experiments with `diff`, looks like the below command produces what you want:

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' diffa.txt diffb.txt
```

Comment: For a one off the pipe method is fine. I would prefer ` perl -ne"print if s/^-//" ` but that is taste.  I think I see what `--changed-group-format='%<'` are doing for me now....

Comment: Thanks. :D I needed something like this to list all my packages between two computers and I used sdiff but this looks a bit better.

Answer (score 18):

More simple method is to use `comm` linux utility (It needs sorted file for input). It writes to standard output:

- lines that are unique for diffa.txt
- lines that are unique for diffb.txt
- lines that are common

and you can suppress each one of them by parameter 1,2 or 3 accordingly. So in youre case it will look like this :

`comm -23 diffa.txt diffb.txt`

It suppresses lines that are unique for diffb.txt, lines that are common and prints out lines that are unique only for diffa.txt

**Source from:**https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/comm.htm

Comment: I found this a lot easier than `diff` which isn't doing what I expect. And I believe it's preinstalled both on BSD (i.e. Mac OS X) as well as Ubuntu so no package manager nightmares.

Comment: If diffa.txt and diffb.txt are not already sorted, we can do the following: `comm -23 <(sort diffa.txt) <(sort diffb.txt)`

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to mention that `comm` expects sorted input files and thus reports different results than `diff`.

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' diffa.txt diffb.txt
```

is universal. Kudos to @vava

Comment: This is a very useful remark.